# Running a listener node in ReadOnly mode

Tags: polkadot-js, nodes

I would like to run a non-validator node (listener node) and prevent it from accepting and broadcasting transactions (ReadOnly mode). Except for accepting transactions, I would like it to behave like a regular node, with the ability to sync with the network and store new blocks.

I checked all the flags that can be passed when running a node but none seem to do what I was after.

I was also thinking to disable the port (like 9944) but that would prevent apps like polkadotJS from reading data from the node.

Is this even possible? Are there any workarounds I can try (like disabling the mempool)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can set up an Archive node for this purpose. Instead of passing the `--validator` flag you need to pass

```
--offchain-worker=always --pruning=archive
```

flags while running the node.

For more details please check this [link](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-sync).